# Getting data extension eventDefinitionKey and Id

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, dataextensions, rest

I'm creating a journey through the journey REST API. I want to add a data extension to that journey. To add a specific data extension, as far as I can see, I need the data extensions eventDefinitionKey and Id and I wonder how I get those, I cant seem to find anything in the docs. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own event definition key, when creating an event definition with the `/eventDefinitions` POST request. This is similar to populating the EVENT DEFINITION KEY when creating the entry source event in the UI:

[image]

Do keep in mind, that it needs to be unique.

Data extension ID is the external key, which is a GUID by default, but can be changed into something more readable (however only in Email Studio and not in Contact Builder):

[image]

Comment: What would that payload look like? 

Like this to create the event:

{
        "type": "Event",
        "name": "New event definition via API",
        "eventDefinitionKey": "Test123",
        "dataExtensionId": "External Key here",
        "iconUrl": "/images/icon-data-extension.svg",
        "arguments":
            {
            "criteria": ""
             },
         "isVisibleInPicker": false,
         "category": "Event"
}

And then provide "Test123" in the metaData as a trigger in the payload to create the journey?

Comment: @ThorChristensen - did you see this discussion: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178935/post-interaction-v1-eventdefinitions-creates-an-event-definition-but-i-cannot-se

Comment: The issue is i want to create a new journey with an existing data extension as entry source. So I cant make a call to get these values as the journey doesnt exist at this point. Its a newly created journey (through REST API) which should use an existing data extension as entry source.